# Is it possible to bring wired headphones into Bluetooth one?

Tags: headphones

Newbie question, but I can't find better place to ask...
I have K. in-ear wired headphones which i love so much, but now their jack broke. I'm not in able to buy expensive wireless headphones, but found a way to bring a second life to my old ones.

What if I buy cheap Bluetooth headphones, cut them and solder existing one?

The found donor has different sensitivity and resistance than my K. does (32 vs 18 ohm and 98(+/-3) vs 106 dB). Should I look up for the same characteristics or what the difference is admissible?

Comment: "but now it's get poor plug" You're going to have to explain what that means if you want any help.

Comment: The easiest way to give your broken headphones a new life is to solder a new jack on.

Comment: I know :( but idea is to make them wireless and forget forever about jack soldering...

Comment: Why not simply solder a new jack to the old headphones and get a separate BT audio receiver like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bluetooth-3-5mm-AUX-Car-Stereo-Audio-Music-Receiver-Wireless-Handsfree-Adapter-/382226043275?var=&epid=2241430625&hash=item58fe72918b:m:m4d_Wh0xqF4oturvszfqZyA  They cost almost nothing.

Comment: It's possible, but soldering the type of wire used in headphone cables is actually fairly difficult.

Comment: 21st century, even smartphone manufacturers remove jack from their phones, wireless era is coming ... for what? ... for jack soldering? :)

Comment: The removal of headphone jacks from smartphones are for either trying to get you to buy their brand of wireless headphones (Looking at you Apple). Or in the case of the newer Android phones they utilise the USB-C connector for audio so still fully capable of wired headphones, albeit with an adapter. There is an increase in wireless devices but they (much like you) need to show respect to the requirements of wired connections and will never make them obsolete

Answer (score -1):

If the impedance of your receiver/amplifier doesn't match that of your speaker, you shouldn't use it. This could cause the device to dissipate too much power and break.

There are boards like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FU12QC8) that may achieve what you're looking for.